How do I change the cell colour of a C# devexpress E4630 VerticalGridControl?
I have a question regarding E4630. In a typical DevExpress GridControl, I can use FormatConditions to change the cell colours of a specific column based on certain conditions. Below is the code that implements the required functionality:
meTableView.FormatConditions.Clear();
var rzero = new FormatCondition()
{
    FieldName = "CalValue",
    Expression = "[CalValue] = 0",
    Format = new DevExpress.Xpf.Core.ConditionalFormatting.Format
    {
        Background = Brushes.White,
        Foreground = Brushes.Black
    }
};
meTableView.AddFormatCondition(rzero);

I would like to use FormatConditions in E4630 as shown above, but I can't implement it. Could you please guide me on what to add or modify in the code behind to implement this functionality? Or, if there is another way to achieve it, please let me know.
(Link: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/e4630/wpf-data-grid-create-a-custom-gridcontrol-that-displays-horizontal-columns)
I referred to the link https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t281921/settings-the-background-color-of-a-wpf-verticalgrid-cell, but it does not provide the solution I am looking for.

You're more likely to get a good answer on devexpress' forum imo.
